# Why am I receiving an invalid URL warning when trying to push files from S3 to DropBox using DropBox's Python SDK?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dropbox, dropbox-sdk

My goal is to take a large number of files held on S3 and be able to move them to dropbox programatically to avoid needing to store them locally and then manually upload.

It would appear that I can accomplish this with DropBox's Python API.  Per the documentation listed [here](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html?highlight=files_save_url#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_save_url_check_job_status), and some additional searches on Google it seems rather straigthforward task.

```
import dropbox

db_key='aklKJHDKdDUMMYKEY'

dbx=dropbox.Dropbox(db_key) # create dropbox object

s3_path='https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucket/myfile.txt'  #set s3 object path

drop_box_path='/root/folder1/myfile.txt'   # set dropbox object path

dbx.files_save_url(drop_box_path, s3_path)   # copy files from S3 to DropBox
```

However, running this will return an API error for invalid URL

```
ApiError: ApiError('4e02eb47d6343e2', SaveUrlError('invalid_url', None))
```

The URL looks to be stemming from the AWS side, not the DropBox side because I can fully connect to the DropBox folders and obtain information from them.

What am I missing here? I have tried both the object URL and the object SRI on amazon, as well as trying to tinker with the various formatting of the link itself ('using // instead of /, etc').

Or maybe there is an entirely different way to accomplish this goal?

I would prefer if this is possible without using a third party intermediary as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914927/transferring-image-from-s3-to-dropbox-efficiently)

Comment: If your S3 object is not public, you'll need to generate and use a presigned linked so Dropbox can access the object.